# Table image viewer

Tags: html, css

I want to arrange the added image horizontally. What will be the css? Please Suggest.

```
<div id="image-viewer">
<table>
    <?php 
    foreach(glob('../images/projects/'.'*') as $filename){
    //echo $filename;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $filename; ?>" height="150" width="200"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td height="34"><a href="projects-body-img.php?id=<?php echo $filename; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');">Delete</a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php

    ?>
    <?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: `display:inline-block` on `img`. If you could provide detailed question with proper `html`, then we could help efficiently.. :)

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP, as well as the CSS you tried

Comment: Actually I am using <?php 
    foreach(glob('../images/projects/'.'*') as $filename){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $filename; ?>" height="150" width="200"></td></tr> to show all picture from a folder and <tr>
        <td height="34"><a href="projects-body-img.php?id=<?php echo $filename; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');">Delete</a></td>

    </tr> to delete every single image.